# Tensorflow Estimator API embedding_column compute neighbourhood

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to implement a similar model to word2vec in tensorflow using the latest estimator API.
The problem I am running into is when I try to evaluate the model. The model itself should be the basis for a recommender system. Now the evaluation metric I would like to use is the Hitrate metric, as follows:

- For each input compute the k neighbourhood.
- Determine if the expected label is in the k neighbourhood, if so it is a successful recommendation.

Now I have setup the model like this:

```
# Map Embeddings Ids to One Hot Tensors
ref_embedding_ids = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_identity(
    key='Reference',
    num_buckets=params['dict_size'],
    default_value=0
)

# Map One Hot Tensors to Dense Embeddings
ref_embeddings = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
    ref_embedding_ids,
    dimension=params['embedding_size']
)
# Actually create the input to the model
input_layer = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, feature_columns=[ref_embeddings])
```

As it is done in the estimator API tutorial. Now as I understand this piece of code, the `input_layer` already only contains the embeddings that are referenced in the feature dictionary with the key `Reference`. Which is awesome since we do not need to keep all the embeddings in memory.
But now if I want to compute the neighbourhood in the evaluation mode, I need to access the embedding vector of all the possible inputs to compute the similarities. However I do not have any reference to those, since the pipeline is setup that only the necessary parts are loaded. I already tried finding out the name of the variable that holds the embeddings and explicitly loading that with `tf.get_variable` but that did not work either.
So my question is how would I compute the neighbourhood for a given embedding id?

Also after being able to compute the neighbourhood I would need to use a metric to keep computing the metric for the whole evaluation set, since the function is called for each batch coming from the dataset. But I guess that is a different question, I just mention it for context.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this? I am trying to do the same thing and can't figure out a way to access the embedding vector to run the nearest-neighbor algorithm on it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by using the `cols_to_vars` parameter to the `tf.feature_column.input_layer` function. 
basically you need to pass an empty dictionary to the tf.feature_column.input_layer which will get populated with the variables that are generated in the input layer. 
below example only contains the model scope of the model_fn function. hope it helps.

```
def my_model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):

  with tf.name_scope('model'):
    num_vocabulary = len(params['vocabulary'])

    #create embedding vectors for history feature
    vocabulary_lookup = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(
      name='vocabulary_lookup',
      mapping=params['vocabulary'],
      default_value=-1,
      num_oov_buckets=1
    )
    #print("lookup: {}".format(vocabulary_lookup))

    #create a bais matrix
    rank_biases = tf.get_variable(name='rank_biases', shape=[num_vocabulary])

    # input layer
    input_variable_ref = {}
    net = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, params['feature_columns'], cols_to_vars=input_variable_ref)
    embedding_metrix = input_variable_ref[params['feature_columns'][0]][0]
    print("embedding metrix => {}".format(embedding_metrix))

    # hidden layers
    for units in params['hidden_units']:
      net = tf.layers.dense(net, units=units, activation=tf.nn.relu)

    # output layer
    with tf.name_scope('DNN_output'):
      logits = tf.layers.dense(net, params['out_layer_dim'], activation=None)
      #print("logits shape: {}".format(logits.shape))
```